# Inject a Mock context in ActivityUnitTestCase Fails

Tags: android, unit-testing

Base from the document in [ActivityUnitTestCase](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ActivityUnitTestCase.html#setActivityContext(android.content.Context))

> void setActivityContext (Context activityContext)
>
> If you wish to inject a Mock, Isolated, or otherwise altered context, you can do so here. You must call this function before calling startActivity(Intent, Bundle, Object). If you wish to obtain a real Context, as a building block, use getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().

but when i use it as shown below

```
ContextWrapper context = mock(ContextWrapper.class);
Resources resources = mock(Resources.class);
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = mock(LayoutInflater.class);

when(context.getPackageName()).thenReturn("package_name");
when(context.getResources()).thenReturn(resources);
when(context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).thenReturn(layoutInflater);
        setActivityContext(context);

Intent intent = new Intent(getInstrumentation().getTargetContext(), MyActivity.class);
startActivity(intent, null, null);
```

it fails with these error, i can't seem to find what i miss, i mock a context because i need to stub some method in context

```
java.lang.AssertionError: LayoutInflater not found.
at android.view.LayoutInflater.from(LayoutInflater.java:231)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.<init>(PhoneWindow.java:306)
at android.app.Activity.attach(Activity.java:6179)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1044)
at android.support.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.newActivity(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:601)
at android.test.ActivityUnitTestCase.startActivity(ActivityUnitTestCase.java:147)
```

Answer (score 0):

Class `ActivityUnitTestCase` is deprecated now in API level 24.
Write Local Unit Tests instead.

Please check : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ActivityUnitTestCase.html#setActivityContext(android.content.Context)

Comment: But i can still use this even it is deprecated. i have read on other thread that it is still possible to use this class.